# SQL select multiple ids firebird

Tags: c++, sql, firebird2.5

I'm use firebird SQL in my C++ project( I'm newby in SQL).
I have table with two rows:

```
|  aID  |  bID |
----------------
|   1   |  2   |
|   1   |  3   |
|   2   |  1   |
|   2   |  2   |
|   2   |  7   |
|   5   |  2   |
|   1   |  7   |
|  ...  |  ... |
................
```

which  aID and bID related as NxN ( multiple to multiple). ( 0 < aID, bID <= 10^6 ).

Now, I have a set of bID's  (b0, b1, b2, ...bK)  where  0<= K <= 10^5.

**Need a unique aID's set which related any of bi ( 0<= i <= K).**

I use  unoptimized way (C++):

```
std::vector<int> bIDs; // given bID's set.

std::set<int> aIDs; // result;

for(std::size_t ix = 0; ix < bIDs.size(); ++ix)
{
       std::vector<int> localAIDs = m_SQLManager.getAIds(bIDs[ix]);
       aIDs.insert( localAIDs.begin(), localAIDs.end() );
}
// where m_SQLManager.getAIDs use for given bi
//"SELECT aID from mytable where bID = bi"  query.
```

**Q: can I get unique aID's  set with one simple  SELECT operation ?**

I thought that

```
"SELECT aID from mytable where bID in ( <here count all bi > )"
```

but, I don't now how large be query string when K - number of b become big ( 10^5), and I don't know that Firebird can or can't support large string query.

Thanks.

Comment: Research "database normal forms".  Your database does not have a 1:1 relationship between the two columns.

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you wnat?

```
select distinct aID
from mytable
where bID between 0 and k;
```

EDIT:

Load your bId into a (temporary) table and do:

```
select distinct t.aID
from mytable t join
     TempBids tb
     on t.bID = tb.bID;
```

Comment: K - is total number of BId, not a value of Bid :)
`ex: k = 2, b1 = 1, b2 = 4`